# Handling bad argument in a function Erlang without using try-catch

Tags: erlang

I want to try to handle a bad argument given to my function *without* using try-catch.

```
countdown(N) when N > 0 ->
    io:format("~p ~n", [N]),
    countdown(N-1);
countdown(N) when N == 0 ->
    io:format("Zero ~n");
countdown(_N) ->
    stop.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use guards in a different way (alongside with `is_integer` function) and finally erlang will throw a new exception whenever a bad argument is passed to the function and you can let some other process do the error recovery.

```erlang
countdown(0) ->
    io:format("Zero ~n");
countdown(N) when N > 0 and is_integer(N) ->
    io:format("~p ~n", [N]),
    countdown(N-1);
countdown(N) when is_integer(N) ->
    io:format("negative number ~n").
```